# Weird crash while accessing array objects at a given index in IOS

Tags: ios

We have the following method where we are trying to access an array object at a given index. The array is `resultArr`. When we do a `resultArr` count it gives us a result of 13. So we know that the array is not null but when we try to do `objectAtIndex` it crashes with the error.

Function:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
      //parse out the json data
   NSError* error;
   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                         JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                         options:kNilOptions 
                         error:&error];

   NSArray *keys = [json allKeys];
   NSLog(@"keys: %@",keys);



   NSArray* htmlAttributions = [json objectForKey:@"html_attributions"]; //2


   NSArray* resultArr = (NSArray *)[json objectForKey:@"result"]; //2

   NSArray* statusArr = [json objectForKey:@"status"]; //2


   NSLog(@"htmlAttributions: %@",htmlAttributions);


   NSLog(@"result: %@", resultArr); //3

   NSLog(@"status: %@", statusArr); //3

   NSLog(@"resultCount: %d",[resultArr count]);

   [resultArr objectAtIndex:0];
  }
```

Error:

```
2012-04-01 22:31:52.757 jsonParsing[5020:f803] resultCount: 13 2012-04-01 22:31:52.759 jsonParsing[5020:f803] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2f900 2012-04-01 22:31:52.760 jsonParsing[5020:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2f900'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is resolved now. Thanks guys.

Comment: You should mark the question as resolved by clicking the check mark by the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is fairly descriptive.  One of the objects that your code expects to be an `NSArray` is actually an `NSDictionary`.  You cannot access fields inside of an `NSDictionary` by using `NSArray` methods (and casting from `NSDictionary*` to `NSArray*` will not convert an `NSDictionary` into an `NSArray`).

This would mean that inside of the JSON, one of your elements was serialized as an object/associative array instead of as a plain array.  You can easily determine which one by looking at your JSON data as text, and finding the item that uses `{` and `}` instead of `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
NSArray* resultArr = (NSArray *)[json objectForKey:@"result"]; //2
```

But that does not make this object (`[json objectForKey:@"result"]`) an NSArray. It is an NSDictionary, and sending it a message that NSDictionary does not respond to (`objectAtIndex:`) causes a crash.

You were able to send it the `count` message without crashing because NSDictionary does happen to respond to the `count` message. But your preconception that this is an array is still mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an NSDictionary* to an NSArray* as you tried to do with this line: `NSArray* resultArr = (NSArray *)[json objectForKey:@"result"];`, then call -objectAtIndex.